# Calcular porcentajes en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un problema al tratar de calcular un porcentaje.

Tengo un formulario con un `maskedtextbox` con este formato `00%` y un `textbox` para digitar una cantidad y otro para recibir el calculo

```
textbox1       maskedtextbox         resultado      textbox1         textbox2

1000      *         10%         =       100     +     1000      =      1100
```

La cadena no tiene el formato correcto:

```
Dim precio, ganancia, resultado As Double
precio = Convert.ToDouble(txtpreciocompra.Text)
ganancia = Convert.ToDouble(txtganancia.Text) 'txtganancia es el maskedtextbox'
resultado = precio * ganancia / 100 +precio
txtprecioventa.Text = resultado.ToString
```

Comment: prueba darle formato a esta expresión txtprecioventa.Text = *resultado.ToString* antes de convertirlo en un string

Comment: no me funciona como sea pero ya encontre la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

al momento de realizar el calculo solo esta haciendo la conversion a double del `textbox` olvidandome de que en realidad era un `maskedtextbox` obviamente tenia que excluir las literales para poder trabajar solo con los valores.

```
txtganancia.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals
ganancia = Convert.ToDouble(txtganancia.Text) / 100
```

Comment: Hola. Podrías ser un poco mas explicito con la respuesta? Gracias